# IOS: set a property in iOS7

Tags: ios6, properties, ios7, synthesize

In my app I have this property (and its `@synthesize` in .m)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *titleHeader;
```

in a `secondViewController`.

The problem is that in `iOS 7` if from `firstViewController` I do:

```
[secondViewController.titleHeader setText:@"title"];
```

it don't work, in `iOS 6` it work.

why?

**EDIT**

I do it:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil code:[object code]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
        [secondViewController.titleHeader setText:[object name]];
        [secondViewController.headerView setBackgroundColor:colorHeaderGallery];
```

Comment: In what way don't it work? is titleHeader != nil? and is secondViewController != nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views of `secondViewController` have not been loaded yet when you set them.
You can verify this by querying for the value of `secondViewController.titleHeader` after pushing the view controller to the navigation stack.

As a fix, you can declare a property in `secondViewController`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *titleHeaderText;
```

then set that property instead of `secondViewController.titleHeader setText`
e.g.

```
secondViewController.titleHeaderText = [object name];
```

After that, in your `secondViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, you can set the text of your label.

```
[self.titleHeader setText:self.titleHeaderText ];
```

**EDIT:**
The behavior of `pushViewController` seems to have changed in iOS 7.
I have tried and replicated your issue.

If you do not want the above change, a workaround is by accessing the view of `secondViewController`, so that its views will be loaded before you call `label setText`.
e.g.

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil code:[object code]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
[secondViewController view];
[secondViewController.titleHeader setText:[object name]];
[secondViewController.headerView setBackgroundColor:colorHeaderGallery];
```

Comment: yes, I checked that secondViewController.titleHeader is nil, but it happen only in iOS 7, disaster!!!

Comment: I have tried and replicated your issue. I added another workaround in my answer above.